# Android: Expand and Collapse Table Row

Tags: android, tablerow

I don't know if this is possible or not so I'll just present my issue and then see if this is something that can be done. So I have a section in a table that contains some quick information, but I want to adjust it so that when a user clicks on a `TableRow` then the row will expand to reveal additional information (stuff that isn't needed in the initial view) and then collapse when that same row is reselected. The `TableRow` is setup with a `GridLayout` (that is fixed to 45dip in layout:height just because that gives the basic overview) and then there are 3 `TextViews` (one is a date label, the other is a title and the last is a message). When the user clicks on the `TableRow` I want to expand the `TableRow` so that the full message in the last `TextView` can be read (since right now it only shows the first line just to save space).
I don't know if any code will help, but here is the code for the `TableRow` layout:

```
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">


    <GridLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dip"
            android:columnCount="2"
            android:rowCount="3"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip">

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="44dip"
                android:id="@+id/alertDateText"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:layout_rowSpan="2"
                android:text="12/12/2013"/>

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/alertTitleText"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="Alert Title"/>

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/alertMessageText"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:textStyle="italic"
                android:textColor="@color/DarkSlateGray"
                android:text="Alert Message"/>
        <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dip"
                android:background="@color/LightSlateGray"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
                android:layout_row="2"
                android:layout_columnSpan="2"/>

    </GridLayout>
</TableRow>
```

And then here's the activity in which I would fill the `TextViews` with data from a `WebService` (I haven't hooked that part up yet since I wanted to make sure I can do the expanding/collapsing feature or else I would need to change the design of this area:

```
Integer alertCount = 3;
    for (int i = 0; i < alertCount; i++) {
        TableRow alertRow = (TableRow)inflater.inflate(R.layout.table_row_alert_holder, alertTable, false);
        alertRow.setClickable(true);
        alertRow.setTag(i);
        alertRow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
            }
        });
        TextView dateText = (TextView)alertRow.findViewById(R.id.alertDateText);
        Date date = new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
        dateText.setText(format.format(date));
        TextView alertHeader = (TextView)alertRow.findViewById(R.id.alertTitleText);
        alertHeader.setText("Alert Title Number: " + i);
        TextView alertMessage = (TextView)alertRow.findViewById(R.id.alertMessageText);
        alertMessage.setText("This is a really long message that will go in one of the alerts since it notifies the user about some kind of form that was declined in the service area");
        alertTable.addView(alertRow);
    }
```

Comment: hey @SalAldana have you found any solution? I faces same problem right now.